# Network printer hangs at "sending print data..."

Tags: macos, network, printing, smb

I can print a test page, but that's it. Anything else I try to print just hangs at "sending print data...".

I'm running OS X 10.7.2 (Lion). My printer is a Canon PIXMA MP210. I'm using the driver from Canon's website. It works when connected via USB. My connection URI is:

```
smb://printme:pleas3@192.168.0.3/GoFlex_Home
```

Anyone seen this before, and know how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed Gutenprint for OS X. The newest version supports my printer. It now prints perfectly using that driver. Weird because it didn't seem like a driver issue. Thanks anyway guys! Hope this helps somebody in the future.

Answer (score 0):

On my Canon Pixma MP970 I have it plugged into the network and Canon's drivers installed.

When I go to System Prefs -> Printers and Scanners, then Add a Printer it finds it under Default. I don't have to put in a printer address at all.

the SMB URI suggests you're accessing it via samba (Windows sharing). Is this a stand-alone networked printer, or being shared from another computer?

Comment: It is being shared through my little NAS.